# Solr - Searching incomplete numbers

Tags: solr

I have a solr schema where i store zipcodes in a text fieldtype.

But solr only gets results if i search for the whole zipcode. 
It doesnt get any results if the zipcode isnt completed.

In example:

I type 12345 - solr gets the zipcode 12345.

I type 1234 - solr doesnt get any results.

Somebody of you got an idea how to resolve this problem?

Must i use any tokenizers on that field or anything else?

THX for help

Comment: Search with a wild card at the end i.e. `q=field:1234*`

Answer (score 3):

Check for [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) filter

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
```

EdgeNGramFilterFactory generates edge grams for the token e.g.

`12345` would generate -> `12, 123, 1234, 12345 .....`

You can use this at index time to generate the tokens.
So when you search for `1234`, documents with `12345` would match

Comment: I would suggest to use EdgeNGramFilterFactory for index time analyzer, only.

Comment: Yup as mentioned in the answer its for Index time use only